# Trouble pretty-printing large json file on linux command line with jq

Tags: json, linux, unix, command-line, pretty-print

I am trying to pretty-print and scroll through sections of an extremely large (tens of gigabytes) human-unreadable json file with jq on the command line.

```
less bigFile.json | jq
```

works but just makes it fly by.

I tried to pipe it back into less like this:

```
less bigFile.json | jq | less
```

but it produced some kind of error.

How do you make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command should look like this:

```
jq -C . bigfile.json | less -r
```

If that exhausts all your memory you might want to try the `-B` option of `less` or even better, use `jq` to filter out the interesting parts.